# Do something when iframe content does window.close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, window.closed

How can I catch that event?

This is my situation:

I have a html page that has a button. When i click the button, a popup shows up. Inside that popup there's an iframe with a different src from my domain.

That iframe contains a page that closes the window when its clicked. But when I click that from my own popup, it doesn't dissapear.

Can I catch this event window.close?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, technically, the popup is in the same domain, "an iframe with a different src **from my domain.**"  I still don't think its possible to "catch" window.close, however.  The popup might be able to bind a function to the button, but I don't think the origin page will be able to.  I'm not sure how to search for it and it's not something I've ever tried to do.

Comment: Looks like I've misunderstood "different src from my domain". Anyway, there's no `window.close` event, and `iframe` can't be closed. If you have control over the iframe code, you could change `window.close()` to `top.close()` to close the pop-up too.

Comment: I mean: if I paste the src url into a new window, it closes automatically.. But I can't catch that event. I can't do onbeforeunload callback on popup. @Teemu

Comment: Just do `top.close()`, if the source is not cross-domain. If it is, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The iFrame will need to send a message to the page that contains it, saying that it wishes to close the window. You need to use the JavaScript PostMessage API to do this.

This approach requires you write code in both domains. If you are unable to do this, then your only option is to not use an iFrame and instead load the other domain directly into the popup.